# Error while duplicating Oracle database after failover, using 11.2.0.4

Tags: oracle, failover, duplication, rman, dataguard

I've recently updated oracle from 11.2.0.1 to 11.2.0.4 and my redundant system is no longer able to recover from failover.

I'm using scripts both on primary and standby node to get back to a state where it is possible to install them as a redundant system again.

It is possible to run the reset script over and over again in all states exept after a failover is performed. The only change is the upgrade to 11.2.0.4. it worked like a charm in 11.2.0.1

I am using Data Guard Broker to maintan the redundancy.

The setup procedure is complicated and is hard to explain here, so I am just asking if someone have faced the same error, and might have a solution how to recover from such situation.

At least, this is the output where it fails:
(Backup step is performed prior to duplicate action)

```
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Nov 14 17:08:48 2014
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : connected to target database: REF15 (DBID=276671931)
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : RMAN> CONNECT AUXILIARY *
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 2> RUN {
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 3> SET UNTIL sequence = 159 thread = 1;
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 4> ALLOCATE AUXILIARY CHANNEL CH1 TYPE DISK;
    2014-11-14 17:08:55 : 5> DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE FOR STANDBY NOFILENAMECHECK DORECOVER;
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : 6> RELEASE CHANNEL CH1;
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : 7> }
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : 8> exit;
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : connected to auxiliary database: REF15 (not mounted)
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : executing command: SET until clause
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : allocated channel: CH1
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : channel CH1: SID=25 device type=DISK
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : Starting Duplicate Db at 14-NOV-14
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : released channel: CH1
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 11/14/2014 17:08:51
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : RMAN-20206: log sequence not found in the repository
    2014-11-14 17:08:56 : Recovery Manager complete.
```

Thanks

Comment: This question might suit better for [DBA Stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Posted there as well now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the DBA section where I found an answer to my question:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83704/error-while-duplicating-oracle-database-after-failover-using-11-2-0-4

Answer (score 0):

Some LOG sequence hasn't been found. Given you request 159, it's that one, or lower.

How do you get that number ? The answer to that, may explain something already. Usuall, it's just a little too high.

Doesn't the ALERT tell you something more ? If you do restore, always have your alert tail-ed.

Comment: This query is used to fetch the log number:
select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log;

Comment: The query is OK, if you ran it at the correct time. Have you queried which logs are backed-up by RMAN ? A tip : if you do any action like restore, you can include such reporting actions. Not only will it prevent you from running it later manually (now, that is), but it will also tell what logs you had at the moment of attempting. That is not necessarily the same as now.